# Incremental denaturation of protein mixtures

Tags: proteins, protein-folding, kinetics

When a protein solution is heated above the denaturation temperature, it seems that denaturation does not happen at the time the temperature is reached, but it takes some time.

I assumed that Brownian motion degrades the protein structure more and more. But I noticed that, in practice, one has a mixture of proteins, and I wonder whether they may behave differently, causing some macroscopic effect?

As an example, taking the clear part of a chicken egg:
No doubt it contains multiple proteins. When heating it slightly above the denaturation point, it coagulates slowly.

I would like to understand in which way that is caused:

- by proteins that denature at some temperature dependent rate - where all proteins behave very similar
- by different proteins denaturing at different temperatures at a much higher rate than others, so that partial coagulation means some proteins are coagulated, and some are not
- of course, it could be both combined, or a completely different way.

Comment: Related: [How does protein denaturation work?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23246/how-does-protein-denaturation-work)